# Doctrine, how to handle multiple flush()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Symfony 2 application I have the following scenario, in this order:

1. in my controller I do some edit on a managed entity (i.e. retrived from db or persisted to the entity manager)
2. if something happen, in my controller (or in a external service got from the container) I do some other edit in other entities, or i
   instanciate some new entities. I want to flush these operations
   (only these described at point 2) immediatly
3. if something else happen, I want to edit some other entities and I want to flush changes made in (1) and in (3). Otherwise, i don't want to flush changes made in (1) and in (3)

Is there a way to do this in Doctrine, e.g. managing multiple unit of work at the same time or something similar? Otherwise I was looking at this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries, i.e. single queries for each update made in point (2) and this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#sql-query-builder for insertions made in point (2) but I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: The "best" approach would be to not use the orm at all.  You might consider using two entity managers.  You might also be able to do $em->flush($entity);  But again, any time you try to go "out of the box" with the orm, you will run into problems.

Comment: @Cerad I think I will try using two em. Searching google and looking method's doc, `$em->flush($entity);` seems to have more cons than pros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your "system" entities and "program" entities and use 2 connections. Have a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can [detach](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) entities that you don't want to be flushed and call `$em->flush();`

```
$em->detach($entity);
```

Comment: If you want to flush detached entities later you can marge them: 
doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities

Comment: @Vladislav this could be good if in point (2) i knew exactly what happened in point (1), but I can't make this assumption

Comment: You can prepare an array of entities (using a try-catch blocks to find if something wrong has happened) that need to be flushed (after all steps passed) and perform $em->clear();, $em->persist($entity) for each entity in an array and $em->flush() then.

Comment: you can split your "system" entities and "program" entities and use 2 connections. 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: another way probably is to create you own persister that would support groups of entities.

Comment: @Vladislav I think I'll try to split entities and use two connections, thus two em.

Comment: Will you mark my answer as a correct one if I post it?

Comment: @Vladislav sure